# Proving the equality of two linear maps, using the linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $W$ is a finite dimensional vector space and $T_1,T_2$ are linear maps from $V$ to $W$.  Show that $null$ $T_1 \subseteq$ $null$ $T_2$ if and only if there exists $S \in L(W, W)$ such that $T_2$ = $S(T_1)$.

Notation: $L (W,W)$ = to the set of all linear operators on W.

I proved this pretty quickly at first, however afterconversation with a classmate, I realized I assumed V was finite.  I am stuck on how to do it without that assumption.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

An idea is to use quotient spaces. Define $E:=V/\ker T_1$, $\overline{T_1}\colon E\to W$ defined by $\overline{T_1}(\overline x)=T_1(x)$ (where $\overline x$ denotes the class modulo $\ker T_1$) and $\overline{T_2}\colon E\to W$ by $\overline{T_2}(\overline x)=T_2(x)$. These maps are well-defined and $\overline{T_1}\colon E\to\operatorname{range}(T_1)$ is bijective (it's an injective map between finite dimensional vector spaces).

If we define $S:=\overline{T_2}\circ \overline{T_1}^{-1}$, we are done.

Comment: Unfortunately, quotient spaces aren't introduced until the next section.

Comment: OK, so I will try to find a solution without this method. Do you know the proof when $\dim W=1$ (i.e. $T_1$ and $T_2$ are linear functionals)?

Comment: yes, I have covered that.  Thanks for your help

Comment: So far my thought process has been, to say $Range T_2 = Span {b_1,...b_n}$ where $b_i$, for $1 \leq i \leq n, \in W$.  So then you can say that $T_1(Null T_2) = \psi$. Thus $T^{-1}_1 (\psi)= null T_2$.  Then you can map $(T_1(T^{-1}_2 B))$ to $B$, $\psi$ to 0, and everything else it doesn't matter what you map it to.  Any suggestions on what to do now?